Adjusting the tab names in cmder
In cmder you can modify tab names, but it doesn't seem to be too flexible.

I have git repositories in a format like:
Company.Team.BigRepo
    /project-name-1
    /project-name-2 

I would like to have the tabs named jupyter (project-name) or jupyter (BigRepo) in case of an active process, and just project-name or BigRepo when the active process is cmder itself.
Is there anyway to do this? Can you hook the naming into some python script for example?
